# Allow only one tag in tag input box in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working in angular, I have created a autocomplete tag box. its working perfect but requirment is, user can select only one tag but in my case multiple tages are getting selected. My code is below.

```
 <div>
         <tags-input ng-model="tags" display-property="name">

         <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" placeholder="Start typing"  min-length="0" debounce-delay="0"></auto-complete>

         </tags-input>

         <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>

        <button class="Button" ng-click="GetAllProjectByKeyId(searchKeyword.key)">Search</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would help if you actually posted the code instead of just some random div from your html

Answer (score 4):

On the documentation page: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api

You can see you can set a max-tags property:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" display-property="name" max-tags="1">
```

Comment: Its correct code, when you add multiple tags you can see the input box is getting red outlined.

Comment: Hi, i tried in this way and, yes, the input box getting red outlined but i can still insert  tags..is it possible block the insert?

Comment: @devgon i am also facing same problem and not get limited tags and i have tried same but  its not working

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this answer is a year late. I ran into the same problem too and came up with the following solution.

You can use the onTagAdding configuration like this: (return false to prevent tag adding)

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" display-property="name" max-tags="1" on-tag-adding="forceOneTag(tags)">
```

In the controller, define forceOneTag as:

```
function forceOneTag(tags) {
    return (tags.length === 0);
}
```

I'm assuming you already found a solution, but hope this will help other people running into the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached it that worked well is added the on-tag-added and the on-tag-removed attributes to the directive and remove/added the readonly and placeholder attributes on the child input element of tags-input.

```
var tagsAddedCount = <initial number of tags>;
var maxTags = <some number>;
var element = jQuery("tags-input"); //update using the control id
scope.onTagAdded = function(tag) {
   ++tagsAddedCount;
   if (!tagsAddedCount >= maxTags) {
        element.find("input").attr("readonly", "readonly");
        element.find("input").attr("placeholder", "");
   }
}
scope.onTagRemoved = function(tag) {
    --tagsAddedCount;
    if (tagsAddedCount < maxTags) {
        element.find("input").removeAttr("readonly");
        element.find("input").attr("placeholder", "Add a tag");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler solution:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" display-property="name" max-tags="1" ng-class="{'hide-input': tags.length > 0}"></tags-input>
```

Then add some custom CSS:

```
tags-input.hide-input .tags input.input{
  display: none ;
}
```

This should hide the input box until the added tag is removes.